# DateTime objects less than or equal to

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Why is'nt **2013-12-28 21:40:43** less than **2013-12-28 22:18:23**

I have this method to retrieve records where the startdates is in the past.

```
repository.Get(x => x.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && (x.EndDate > DateTime.Now || !x.EndDate.HasValue)
```

If I change StartDate to **2013-12-27** the records are fetched.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Solved by:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

And using that in the expression instead.

Comment: I guess it's some kind of time zone issue.

Comment: But the debugger prints out the above dates...it's on my local machine.

Comment: But yes, you are most likely right, if I just change the hour with -1 the records are being fetched. It must have something to do with our -1h during winter time in Sweden :)

Comment: Placing  `! Hasvalue` as the _last_ term in a condition does hurt my eyes.

Comment: Post the exact definition of `x.StartDate` , it must be an offset type.

Comment: Henk Holterman sorry, not my intention to hurt your eyes :)
But please elaborate...it's an optional field.

Comment: @Josef - you should check whether the field has a value **before** you try and do a comparison on it.  If it doesn't have a value (i.e., it's null) then `x.EndDate > DateTime.Now` will throw a NRE.

Comment: Hm, I have alot of nulled EndDate's in my table. Does not cause any exception.
It just fetches records where EndDate is in the future OR EndDate is null(which means that the request is ended on a manual basis).

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer

Comment: @Tim I was curious about this too, so I did a little digging. _[When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to false except for != (not equal).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)_ It's under the 'Operators' section. It is a bit strange to see the null check after other comparisons when working with reference types, but in this case with a `DateTime?` it works out to be perfectly valid.

Comment: @IchabodClay - Thanks for the info.  That's a useful thing to know (I'll have to share it with my teammates).

Comment: @Tim - excellent find on the evaluation to false on expressions with a nullable type.

Comment: @MetroSmurf - Actually that was found by Ichabod Clay, not me.  But yes, that was a good find.

Comment: @Tim - doh! Better read the author, not the @...

Comment: @IchabodClay - "perfectly valid" is not the same as readable. Comparisons with `null` are confusing and attract errors. Always avoid or at least separate them.

Answer (score 1):

you database and you website in 2 machine?
DateTime.Now in linq will translate sql function,so it use the db machine time
and var now=DateTime.Now use the website machine time
so check the database machine system datetime

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by storing the DateTime.Now in a local variable and using that in the expression instead.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Downvoted. `.ToLocalTime()` is a no-op (no change in value between old instance and new instance) when used on the output of `DateTime.Now`. The `Kind` property is already `Local`!

Comment: And it was in a local variable as above (as opposed to inside an expression tree which is interpreted magically by Linq-to-SQL)? You must be wrong. Edit: I could see how it could change something (possibly) to pull out the `DateTime.Now` call to before the lambda expression(?).

Comment: As above.

From: 
repository.Get(x => x.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && (x.EndDate > DateTime.Now || !x.EndDate.HasValue)

To
repository.Get(x => x.StartDate <= now && (x.EndDate > DateTime.Now || !x.EndDate.HasValue)

Comment: I am sure it will be the same without `ToLocalTime` as long as you keep the `DateTime.Now` call in the location before the lambda expression, in a local variable.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, josef, could either of you explain _why_ that variable solves the problem? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am not sure if/why that works. Initially I commented because I *knew* that `ToLocalTime()` could never be useful when used the way it was. I am not sure what `Get` is here. If it takes in an `Expression<Func<X, bool>>` for example, it could be the case that "`DateTime.Now`" in that expression was translated into some instruction on a remote machine, like a SQL server or a web server, which would then find the current time on that machine. On the other hand the local variable will certainly hold the current time on "this" machine. This is pure guessing on my side. Not my idea.

Comment: I don't know why it worked to be honest. It just did, maybe it has to do with the database being on windows azure och the app being on my local machine.

Yes Jeppe, Get() takes Expression<Func<X, bool>>.

Comment: Yes, translation to SQL could be the answer, not so obvious.